# UITableViewCell unintentionally placing checkmark on unwanted rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am making a music genre picking application and when I go to my table to select genres, I select a row and it selects a random row about 10 or so down from my selection.

My code for the selection is:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let genresFromLibrary = genrequery.collections
    let rowitem = genresFromLibrary![indexPath.row].representativeItem
    print(rowitem?.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyGenre) as! String
    )
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cells are reused by default when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called. This causes the cells to have the wrong data when you don't keep track of the indexPaths that have been selected. You need to keep track of the index paths that are currently selected so you can show the appropriate accessory type in your table view.

One way of doing it is to have a property in your UITableViewController that just stores the index paths of the selected cells. It can be an array or a set.

```
var selectedIndexPaths = Set<IndexPath>()
```

When you select a row on `didSelectRowAt`, add or remove the cell from `selectedIndexPaths`, depending on whether the index path is already in the array or not:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
         // The index path is already in the array, so remove it.
         selectedIndexPaths.remove(indexPathIndex)
    } else {
         // The index path is not part of the array
         selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
    }

    // Show the changes in the selected cell (otherwise you wouldn't see the checkmark or lack thereof until cellForRowAt got called again for this cell).
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

Once you have this, on your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, check if the indexPath is in the `selectedIndexPaths` array to choose the `accessoryType`.

```
if selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
    // Cell is selected
    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = .none
}
```

This should solve the problem of the seemingly random cells that are checked every 10 cells down or so (which, is not random, it's just that the cell with the checkmark is being reused).

Comment: In `didSelectRowAt` it is probably better to simply reload the row at `indexPath` after updating `selectedIndexPaths` instead of obtaining and updating a cell.

Comment: @rmaddy Nice point. I forgot about reloadRows. I will update my answer to change that.

Comment: Your code will also be far more efficient if you make `selectedIndexPaths` a `Set` instead of an `Array`. Then removing an index path will be much more efficient.

Comment: Yeah I mentioned it can be an array or a set, and normally I use arrays in these examples since most newcomers may be more comfortable with them. I have changed it anyway, since I had already done the `reloadRows` change. Thanks for pointing all this out, @rmaddy!

Comment: Now that you made it a set you need to redo the code that removes the index path. You no longer need to get the index.

Comment: @rmaddy yeah, I also need to change some things (like the `+=` operator that doesn't work on sets). Gonna get it done in a second.

Comment: That should do it. Let me know if you spot anything else. I don't have a project handy right now to test if it still works, but it should.

Answer (score 0):

Because `cellForRow` returns a cached cell you generated. When scrolling out of the screen the order of cells are changed and cells are reused. So it seems "randomly selected".

Don use `cellForRow`, instead record selection data.

Here's code works in a single view playground.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let tableView = UITableView()
    var selection: [IndexPath: Bool] = [:]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        view.addSubview(tableView)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        tableView.frame = self.view.bounds
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "c")
        if let sc = cell {
            sc.accessoryType = .none
            let isSelected = selection[indexPath] ?? false
            sc.accessoryType = isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
            return sc
        }
        return UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "c")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = NSNumber(value: indexPath.row).stringValue
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selection[indexPath] = true
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 30
    }

}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Comment: Why do you set the `accessoryType` twice in `cellForRowAt`?

Comment: This is the first time I see it being done this way. I feel it would get complicated since you would have to keep track of all the index paths and their respective boolean values all the time, specially if your table view controller is very dynamic (cell insertions, deletions, moving, etc).